# Using only the definition of matrix multiplication, prove that multiplication of matrices is associative

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

i'm trying to prove the following statement is true.

$(AB)C = A(BC)$ where A, B and C are all matrices.

before starting my proof, i define $B = (b_1, ..., b_p), C = (c_1, ... c_p)$ where each element of these definitions of B and C are columns of those matrices.

first, my proof for $(AB)C = A(BC)$

$AB = A(b_1, ..., b_p) = (Ab_1, ..., Ab_p)$

it follows that:

$(AB)C = (Ab_1, ..., Ab_p)C = (Ab_1C, ..., Ab_pC) = A(b_1C, ..., b_pC) = A(BC)$

next, my proof for $A(BC) = (AB)C$

$BC = B(c_1, ... c_p) = (Bc_1, ... Bc_p)$

it follows that:

$A(BC) = A(Bc_1, ... Bc_p) = (ABc_1, ... ABc_p) = (AB)(c_1, ... c_p) = (AB)C$

i think i'm right but i'm unsure of the quality of my proof.

edit: i think i may have fixed my proof using the definition of matrix multiplication above. but i want to try to see if i've gotten my proof right using the usual definition.

let $(AB)_{ij} = $$\sum_{k=1}^nA_{ik}B_{kj}$ and $C_{kj}$, so:

$(AB)C = $$\sum_{k=1}^n(AB)_{ik}C_{kj} = $$\sum_{k=1}^n($$\sum_{l=1}^mA_{il}B_{lk})C_{kj} = $$\sum_{k=1}^n$ $\sum_{l=1}^m$$A_{il}B_{lk}C_{kj}$

and

$A(BC)=$$\sum_{l=1}^mA_{il}(BC)_{lj}=$$\sum_{l=1}^mA_{il}($$\sum_{k=1}^nB_{lk}C_{kj})=$$\sum_{l=1}^m$$\sum_{k=1}^nA_{il}B_{lk}C_{kj}$

therefore $(AB)C=A(BC)$.

Comment: Why is $(AB)C=(Ab_1,\ldots, Ab_p)$ and why is $(Ab_1,\ldots, Ab_p)=(ACb_1,\ldots, ACb_p)$?

Comment: You don't need to prove both $(AB)C=A(BC)$ and $A(BC)=(AB)C$. These two equations are equivalent since "$=$" is symmetric. However, I can't follow the steps in either of your proofs. In the first you wrongly end up with $A(CB)$ but claim it is $A(BC)$. In the second you seem to use $A(Bc_i)=(AB)c_i$ for columns $c_i$, did you prove that?

Comment: I think you need to tell us what your definition of matrix multiplication actually is. Mine has nothing to do with column vectors.

Comment: regarding first comment: these were copying errors on my part. thank you for pointing them out. i've fixed them.

Comment: regarding second comment: if i define $BC = (b_1, ..., b_p)C = (b_1C, ..., b_pC)$ and use this to show $(AB)C = A(BC)$, would this be better?

Comment: regarding third comment: i've been given two definitions of matrix multiplication in lecture and i'm working with the simpler one. i've used it on some previous computations too. the other definition is similar to the one given in the first answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the matrices are $n\times n$, that $A$ has components $a_{ij}$, $B$ has components $b_{ij}$ and $C$ has components $c_{ij}$. I also assume your definition of matrix multiplication is that the $i,j$ component of $AB$ is $\sum_{k=1}^na_{ik}b_{kj}$.

Then the $i,j$ component of $(AB)C$ is $$\sum_\ell\left(\sum_ka_{ik}b_{k\ell}\right)c_{\ell k}$$ and the $i,j$ component of $A(BC)$ is $$\sum_k\left(a_{ik}\sum_\ell b_{k\ell}c_{\ell j}\right)$$

A little thought shows that both these expressions are the sum of all the $n^2$ terms $$a_{ik}b_{k\ell}c_{\ell j}\text{ with }1\le k,\ell\le n$$